# CreateJS: TweenJS timeline tween change properties multiple time without chaining

Tags: javascript, animation, createjs, chaining, tweenjs

In this example the expected result is to make the circle fadeOut then fadeIn. This works ok with chaining. The commented line in the snippet

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(0).to({alpha:0.1},2000).wait(2000).to({alpha:1},2000)
```

It does not work if I separate them into 2 separate calls on the same object. Callbacks are not an option as there may be other tweens to other children between the fading in and fading out of the circle.

Tweenjs seems to override all other previous properties change and just keep the last one.
Any suggestions on this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>TweenJS: Canvas Tweening Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>

<script id="editable">
 function init() {
  stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas1");
  var timeline=new createjs.Timeline();

  var circle = new createjs.Shape();
  circle.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
  stage.addChild(circle);
  
  timeline.addTween(
   //circle should fadeTo 0.1 then back to 1
   //createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(0).to({alpha:0.1},2000).wait(2000).to({alpha:1},2000) //works
   createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(0).to({alpha:0.1},2000), //this tween is ignore
   createjs.Tween.get(circle).wait(2000).to({alpha:1},2000) //only this tween fires
  )
  
  
  timeline.setPaused(false);

  createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);
  createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
 }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
<canvas id="canvas1" width="960" height="350"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed an issue as it is stated in the documentation:

> Multiple tweens can point to the same instance, however if they affect
>   the same properties there could be unexpected behaviour. To stop all
>   tweens on an object, use removeTweens or pass override:true in the
>   props argument.

Passing override means all previous tweens will be killed off - it kinda defeats the purpose of a the timeline.
As I explained, I am working with a long list of tweens for multiple options. I was excepting - addTween to chain the animations automatically - this does not happen. Thankfully, it can be fixed with a simple for loop.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TweenJS: Canvas Tweening Example</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>

  <script id="editable">
    function init() {
      stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas1");
      var timeline = new createjs.Timeline();

      var circle = new createjs.Shape();

      circle.graphics.beginFill("#FF0000").drawCircle(50, 50, 50);
      stage.addChild(circle);

      circle.anims = [
        [0, {
            alpha: 0.1
          },
          2000
        ],
        [0, {
            alpha: 1
          },
          2000
        ]
      ]

      for (var i in circle.anims) {
        var c = createjs.Tween.get(circle)
        for (var j in circle.anims) {
          var tw = circle.anims[j];
          c.wait(tw[0]);
          c.to(tw[1], tw[2]);
        }
      }

      timeline.addTween(c)
      timeline.setPaused(false);

      createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);
      createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="init();">
  <canvas id="canvas1" width="960" height="350"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

I am just feeding all tween properties the target object as array then creating the full tween using a for loop. Afterwards, I just add it to the timeline.

Thank you again for the answers. Hopefully, this will help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The operation you are using is asynchronous, so you must use the method "call" to continue execution after the first invocation of tween, like this:

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, false, null, false).wait(100).to({alpha:0},2000).call(function() {
    createjs.Tween.get(circle, false, null, false).wait(1000).to({alpha:1},2000);
});
```

You can also pass in the reference to a named function, e.g.

```
createjs.Tween.get(circle, false, null, false).wait(100).to({alpha:0},2000).call(function_name);
```

So you can simulate chaining with a recursive function by having an array containing all the operations you need to execute, and a function extracting the elements in the array one at a time and executing them, and passing itself as a parameter of the .call method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Callbacks is not what I am looking for as there could be other tweens happening between fadeIn and fadeOut. I calculate the duration to create a succesion. My problem is that if I do not use tween chaining, tweenjs overrides properties change and keeps just the last one. In my case if ignore the fact that I want to make the circle fadeout then after a few other tweens on the timeline (not related to the circle) I want the circle to fadeIn.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is due to the fact that properties tweened with TweenJS are deterministic. This means that you can jump to any point in a tween, and it will be where you expect it. If you make multiple tweens that manage a single property, neither can be deterministic.

I recommend either chaining (which I know you said you didn't want), or using a chained "call" to kick off a tween when another one is done. Perhaps not what you were hoping for, but hopefully gives you a better idea of why this doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Lanny, thank you very much for taking the time to share this answer for me. Indeed, chaining is the way I shall go. I plan to feed the wait, properties object and duration as a property to the target object then link them together with a for loop and call it using eval. Thank you again for your answer.